# Use Mac Pro as time machine, server and editing station?

Tags: time-machine, webserver, incremental-backup, mac-pro

**Background:**

My fiancée needs a Mac Pro for movie editing and rendering. I need a web server and a backup solution for my MacBook Pro.

**Idea**

We thought we could split the costs of the Mac Pro and set it up to act as both a web server and a backup device.

**Question**

Is this a good idea?
Specifically:

1. Is it easy to set it up to incrementally backup one or several laptops over wifi? And what software would you recommend?
2. Is it silent and stable enough to run a web server continuously?
3. Will it manage all this, including simultaneous editing?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dan. Unfortunately, SuperUser.com is not the place to ask for software or shopping recommendations, and in the case of your question, it will elicit extended discussion for what amounts to be a subjective question. Please read the [FAQ] and edit your question (which has some merit) to fit the requirements.

Comment: Thanks @RandolphWest. I removed the subjective subquestion related to buying advice.

Answer (score 1):

1. I use rsync for backing up a selection of folders from my Macbook Pro to my Ubuntu box. With rsync you can make incremental backups. Rsync is a command line program that comes with every mac. You can automate your rsync backups by putting them in a cron job. A nice article on rsync can be found here: http://maketecheasier.com/make-incremental-backups-with-rsync/2010/08/25

Unfortunately, I cannot help you with your other questions.

Comment: I use `rsync` for all my backup needs.